# Loop over an array of objects and format values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Inside my API response of data, I'm trying to loop over an array of objects in `items`.
I need to format each value inside the object.  Each key in the `items` list of objects corresponds to a format type in my `header` key.  I also have a `getFormat` function to help format the values

My question is how would I do this given the structure I have?

```
// Data
const data = {
  header: {
    date: {
      feature: "Date",
      format: "date",
    },
    description: {
      feature: "Description",
      format: "text",
    },
    salary: {
      feature: "Salary",
      format: "currency",
    },
    score: {
      feature: "Score",
      format: "float",
    },
    useage: {
      feature: "Useage",
      format: "percentage",
    },
  },
  items: [
    {
      date: "2021-02-08",
      description: "Light",
      salary: "50000",
      score: 20,
      useage: 20,
    },
    {
      date: "2021-02-08",
      description: "Heavy",
      salary: "60000",
      score: 50.235,
      useage: 30,
    }
  ],
};

// format helper
export const getFormat = (value: any, format: FormatProp) => {
  let options: Intl.NumberFormatOptions;

  switch (format) {
      case "currency":
          options = { currency: "USD", style: "currency" };
          break;
      case "percentage":
          options = { style: "percent", maximumFractionDigits: 2 };
          break;
      case "float":
          options = { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 };
          break;
      case "text":
          return value;
      case "date":
          return value;
      default:
          throw Error("Wrong Format!");
  }
  return Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", options).format(value);
};

export type FormatProp =
  | "currency"
  | "percentage"
  | "float"
  | "text"
  | "date";
```

Desired Output

```
[{
  date: "2021-02-08",
  description: "Light",
  salary: "$50,000.00",
  score: "20.00",
  useage: "20%",
},
{
  date: "2021-02-08",
  description: "Heavy",
  salary: "$60,000",
  score: "50.24",
  useage: "30%",
}]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to iterate over the data items to get a new array that has the correct output. You also want to go through each `key` in the object and and format the associated `value` based on what the key is and how it's represented in header.

So we will `map` over the items, use `Object.entries` to get an array of `key` and the associated `value` and then use `reduce` to build the item object key by key.

```js
// Data
const data = {
  header: {
    date: {
      feature: 'Date',
      format: 'date',
    },
    description: {
      feature: 'Description',
      format: 'text',
    },
    salary: {
      feature: 'Salary',
      format: 'currency',
    },
    score: {
      feature: 'Score',
      format: 'float',
    },
    useage: {
      feature: 'Useage',
      format: 'percentage',
    },
  },
  items: [{
      date: '2021-02-08',
      description: 'Light',
      salary: '50000',
      score: 20,
      useage: 20,
    },
    {
      date: '2021-02-08',
      description: 'Heavy',
      salary: '60000',
      score: 50.235,
      useage: 30,
    },
  ],
};

// format helper
const getFormat = (value, format) => {
  let options;

  switch (format) {
    case 'currency':
      options = {
        currency: 'USD',
        style: 'currency'
      };
      break;
    case 'percentage':
      options = {
        style: 'percent',
        maximumFractionDigits: 2
      };
      break;
    case 'float':
      options = {
        maximumFractionDigits: 2,
        minimumFractionDigits: 2
      };
      break;
    case 'text':
      return value;
    case 'date':
      return value;
    default:
      throw Error('Wrong Format!');
  }
  return Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', options).format(value);
};

const output = data.items.map(item => // iterate over items
  Object.entries(item).reduce((a, [key, value]) => { // for each item get the key/value pairs
    const header = data.header[key]; // find the associated header
    return {
      ...a,
      [key]: header ? getFormat(value, header.format) : value, // if the header exists lets get the formatted value back, else return the previous value
    };
  }, {}),
);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 2):

### Typing the Response

We know that our unformatted version contains a mix of `string` and `number` values.  We also know that when we are done formatting, all of the values will have been converted to `string`.

We know that `data.header` contains the same keys as the elements of `data.items` and that the values in `data.header` contain a property `format`.  The value of `format` is either `FormatProp` or `string`, depending on how strict you want to be.  It is easier if you use `string` since typescript will interpret the string values in your `data` object as `string` rather than as their literal values (unless using `as const`).

Putting that all together, the API response can be typed as:

```
type Data<Keys extends string> = {
  header: Record<Keys, {
      feature: string;
      format: string;
    }>,
  items: Array<Record<Keys, number | string>>
}
```

### Typing the Map Functions

We know that the `.format()` function of an `Intl.NumberFormat` only accepts `number`, so passing it a value with type `any` isn't the best.  We can do better.  Let's only pass it `number` values.  We will let the cases associated with `string` fields throw the error.

```
export const getFormat = (value: number, format: FormatProp): string => {
  let options: Intl.NumberFormatOptions;

  switch (format) {
      case "currency":
          options = { currency: "USD", style: "currency" };
          break;
      case "percentage":
          options = { style: "percent", maximumFractionDigits: 2 };
          break;
      case "float":
          options = { maximumFractionDigits: 2, minimumFractionDigits: 2 };
          break;
      default:
          throw Error("Wrong Format!");
  }
  return Intl.NumberFormat("en-US", options).format(value);
};
```

It's actually better if we allow any `string` as `format` if that's what you did in `Data`.  But I keep the `FormatProp` in a union with `string` for the sake of autocomplete.

```
export const getFormat = (value: number, format: FormatProp | string): string => {
```

When mapping, it's basically the same thing that @Mateusz is doing except that we need some extra annotations.  Specifically, we have to type the empty object `{}` that we `reduce` to as the type for the complete object `Record<Keys, string>` and we have to type the array from `Object.entries` as `[Keys, string | number][]` in order to get the keys as their literal values and not just `string`.

```
const formatItems = <Keys extends string>(data: Data<Keys>): Array<Record<Keys, string>> => {
  return data.items.map( item => {
    // we have to assert the correct type here with `as` or else all keys are `string`
    return (Object.entries(item) as [Keys, string | number][]).reduce( 
      (formatted, [key, value]) => {
        formatted[key] = typeof value === "number" ? getFormat(value, data.header[key].format) : value;
        return formatted;
    }, {} as Record<Keys, string>); // assert the type for the incomplete object
  })
}
```

Calling `formatItems(data)` with this particular `data` object now returns the following type:

```
Record<"date" | "description" | "salary" | "score" | "useage", string>[]
```

You can access any of those properties on the object and typescript knows that those properties always exist and are always of type `string`.

Since we used the generic `Keys` rather than relying on this particular object type, you can call `formatItems` with other data sets and get similarly well-typed responses.